# Where is the full story of Radha Krishna?

Tags: krishna, radha

In which Hindu scriptures can we find the stories related to Radha and Krishna where Krishna purified Radha from her anger, moh, jealousy, fear, ego .

Comment: "Where" as in ? Are you looking for any book reference ?

Comment: This is the best I can do .. @Wikash can you please do some corrections or let me know where to do it?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto anything is good book or wherever the full life story or the incidents I mentioned similar I can find.

Comment: @PranitaGupta you can refer to Brahma Vaivarta Purana... The stories of Radha and Krishna are mentioned there...

Comment: @wikash_ If you know proper grammar and spelling then please edit, no one stopped you. But saying "Omg, what a terrible post. Please use proper grammar and spelling." Is **very unfriendly**  so please stop doing that

Comment: 1)Where is the full story of Radha Krishna? Where Krishna purified Radha from her anger , moh , jealousy , fear , ego. 2)Radha born blind , and when met with Krishna she opened her eyes . 3)Radha have a cusin named chandravali and 4)Brahmaji do the marriage of Radha Krishna . Ayan named person was in love with Radha . These are four incidents you mean, yes? If No then please tell me so that I or others could edit it.

Comment: "Omg, what a terrible post"well I did not say it like this @KrishnaShweta

Comment: @wikash I copy-pasted your comment. You said like that

Comment: That is not true my friend. I did not say that. Please do not twist my words. @KrishnaShweta

Comment: Btw, only one question per post is allowed, otherwise it will be closed as "too broad". So please ask each question separately

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto are you being sarcastic or serious?

Comment: About: "Such a terrible liar You're :D" @TheLittleNaruto Also, I noticed that you deleted your post.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Good one. How do you know I lied (while it is not true)?

Comment: @Krishna shweta thanks for support ,you are right that comment was harsh, one can tell me about where I can find any of these incidents (Kam se Kam ek bhi chalega) will be fine so I wrote them together.

Comment: @Pranita If you find anything rude then you can flag them. BTW, please write these questions as 5 different posts, you will definitely get answers one or the other day. Please split them and write separate post for each question.